# $E'\otimes_kF'=E'\otimes_k F\cap E\otimes_kF'$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, tensor-products

Let $E,F$ be two vector spaces over a field $k$. Let $E'$ be a subspace of $E$ and $F'$ a subspace of $F$. Let $i:E'\rightarrow E$ and $j:F'\rightarrow F$ be the canonical injections. Is it true that
$$\text{Im}(i\otimes j)=\text{Im}(i\otimes 1)\cap\text{Im}(1\otimes j)?$$

The direction $\text{Im}(i\otimes j)\subset\text{Im}(i\otimes 1)\cap\text{Im}(1\otimes j)$, since $i(x)\otimes j(y)=i(x)\otimes y=x\otimes j(y)$ for all $x\in E'$ and $y\in F'$. I'm not sure how to prove the other direction.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $E''$ be a linear complement of $E'$ in $E$ and $F''$ be a linear complement of $F'$ in $F$, so $E=E'\oplus E''$ and $F=E'\oplus E''$.  Since tensor products distribute over direct sums, we have $$E\otimes F=(E'\otimes F')\oplus (E'\otimes F'')\oplus (E''\otimes F')\oplus (E''\otimes F'')$$ (where I am identifying all the tensor products on the right with their images in $E\otimes F$ under the inclusion maps).  With respect to this direct sum decomposition, $E'\otimes F$ consists of the elements whose last two coordinates are $0$, and $E\otimes F'$ consists of the elements whose second and fourth coordinates are $0$.  So the intersection is the elements whose last three coordinates are all $0$, which is just $E'\otimes F'$.

(Note that the use of something like linear complements here is crucial.  In particular, this result is *not* true in more general contexts where such complements might not exist.  For instance, if you were taking a tensor product of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules, the intersection of the images of $2\mathbb{Z}\otimes\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}\otimes 2\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Z}\otimes\mathbb{Z}$ is strictly larger than the image of $2\mathbb{Z}\otimes 2\mathbb{Z}$.)